# Error in Angular 9 App in Production On Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application

I have a strange error deploying and Angular 9 app in production mode on an Nginx Server.
Long story short:
 I must reload the site at least 5 times until my web page loads. On the first attempts I get 503 to certain files.
Here is what is happening:

**First time accessing the webiste:**
[image: First time accessing the webiste]

**Reload nr.1 :**
[image]

**Reload nr.2 :**
[image]

**Reload nr.3 :**
[image]

**Reload nr.4 :**
[image]

**Reload nr.5 :**
[image]

**Nginx Config:**
This config is done in a separate file and then is linked with a a symbolic link
[image]

Is worth mentioning that I have an **APP_INITIALIZER** provider in **core.module**

**UPDATE 1:**

The files with red that are not loaded have a Response Header of 
**Content-Type: text/html**
Why is Nginx Returning Them as HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

For those in this situation. The problem is with the rate limiter which is too sensitive